# Нужен пример использования поиска в Tkinter Treeview Python

Tags: python, tkinter, search, treeview

В общем, в таблице Treeview при вводе символов с клавиатуры должен осуществляться переход на строку, соответствующую введенным символам. Т.е. динамический поиск по одной из колонок таблицы. Может есть у кого подобный пример?

Comment: Посмотрите код в этом вопросе/ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1187779/1365

Comment: Спасибо, но не то. Там поле ввода и кнопка поиска. Мне нужно чтоб поиск работал при вводе с клавиатуры сразу по таблице.

Comment: Ну, тогда нужна какая-то эмуляция скрытого текстового поля, при нажатии на кнопку она добавляется в строку-буфер, по тексту из буфера делать поиск как в ответе по ссылке. По esc (например) делать очистку буфера.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую так реализовать.